# How to call a SQL Server Stored Procedure as a Crystal Data source?

Tags: sql-server, crystal-reports

I have a SQL Server function with one parameter that returns a table.  The SS function acts like a Stored Procedure.  I want to use the result of this function as the data source for a Crystal report.

I am able to define the function as a database table if I use a static value for the parameter.  But I need to use the value of a report parameter as the SQL Server function parameter.  I.e., I want a pay period starting date (a parameter for the report) to be entered by the user when the report is launched and this date should also be passed to the SQL Server function to generate the data table for the report.

Can someone suggest how this is done?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Follow these steps

1. Add crystal report.
2. Right click on database fields and choose "Database Expert".
3. Under "Create New Connection", choose ole db connection and create
   it.
4. Now expand new connection and under stored procedures you will see
   your functions. Choose the one you want to create report.

Comment: This describes the standard process for connecting a table or stored proc.  The challenge I have is passing a Crystal parameter to the stored proc or function.

Comment: You must have variable of type CrystalDecisions.CrystalReports.Engine.ReportDocument in your code which you used to load report. In this variable loop through collection "ParameterFields" and set values to each parameter. something like reportDocument.SetParameterValue("@CompanyID", 1)

Comment: I'm not sure if "your code which you used to load report" applies.  I am not controlling this report from an external code set.  I want the report user to work entirely within the Crystal Reports application.  If there is a way that I can define a pre-print script within the report then it sounds like that is what I need - but don't know how to access.